# API response JSON waiting for the final result

Tags: javascript, android, json, api, android-asynctask

I'm new here and new to JavaScript programming in Android Studio too.
I'm working on a app that uses the API called page2images that gives back the screenshot of a website by searching a URL. The response is a JSON code, but when I make a call I see something like this:

```
{"status":"processing","estimated_need_time":50}
```

after a while it shows me this:

```
{"status":"finished","image_url":"http://api.page2images.com/ccimages/fd/fb/jDgCCNYu2kyKwKDs.png","duration":1,"left_calls":"2910","mobileok":"yes","ori_url":"http:\/\/www.twitter.com"}
```

that's what I need.. but how can I make the program wait till the second code is showed? the URL is the same and if I refresh the page I can see the `estimated_need_time` decreasing but if I do the parsing of `image_url` I would have to wait the right response but when I click the button the app would have to do all by its own..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly see your problem, but If I do just wait "estimated_need_time" and call the api again.
Parse the first answer, set for example a handler to wait responded amount of seconds and call the api again. It should solve your problem.

Comment: It is variable, I'd like that it gives me the final response just afer finished..

Comment: Se sei italiano rispondi pure in italiano ahah